# Symfony Form - display errors only when specific button is clicked

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Is there any smart solution to prevent from showing form errors when form is submitted but some specified button is not clicked?

Here is part of my controller:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid() && $form->get('pay')->isClicked()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the value of whether the form button is clicked back to your twig template and use that as your condition:

```
return array('payIsClicked' => $form->get('pay')->isClicked());
```

Then in Twig:

```
{% if payIsClicked %}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
{% endif %}
```

If you aren't using error bubbling and want to apply this to every field, you could [modify the `form_row` block](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-theming) to deal with that value and whether or not to display the errors for each field (or just do manual `if` statements for each).

That's just one example - without knowing more details it's difficult to answer your question.